# spiking neural network in combination with deep CNNs

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a deep CNN in forms of LENET5 is it possible to apply spiking convolutional  neural networks [leaky integrate-and-fire (LIF) spiking model] in combination with LENET5 ? if so, in which section of LENET5 can I apply this approach , in order to speed up the network.(I code in python)